# run a thread by implementing runnable

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable

I would like to ask some question about running a thread in android.
Can anyone tell me when will the thread be called in this situation?

```
public class PhotoDecodeRunnable implements Runnable {
...
  @Override
  public void run() {
    /*
     * Code you want to run on the thread goes here
     */
    ...
  }
...
}
```

Is this thread always stand by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a thread, but it just a class that implements the runnable interface. Calling the `run` method on an instance of `PhotoDecodeRunnable`, will result in having the code running in the context of the thread that called the method itself. `Thread` has a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.Runnable)) that takes a `Runnable`  as parameter. Calling

```
   Thread thread = new Thread(new PhotoDecodeRunnable());
   thread.start();
```

will spawn a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call this with a Thread, what you have is a Runnable, do either this:

```
Thread(new PhotoDecodeRunnable()).start();
```

or use the android built in `AsynctTask`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html